# HTML CSS Align two elements the same line

Tags: html, css

[image: Panel]

I need to create the above HTML.

It's a h3 with a blue background and to the right is an SVG for a tick.

I need to have both elements sitting on the same line, and the SVG embedded within the h3.

This looks so easy, but I can't figure out how to do this.

What is the best way to achieve the above?

Comment: you can use background image or put img tag inside h3 and float to right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<h3 style="background-color:blue;">About You 
    <img src="image.png" style="float:right;display:block;">
</h3>
```

Comment: The core point is the `float:right;display:block;`, you can add the same style to an inline `<svg>`

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a `<h3>` with a image in it and apply padding to `<h3>` for top and bottom space.

```css
h3{
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:18px;
  color:#fff;
  background:blue;
  margin:0;
  padding:5px 10px;
}
h3 img{
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<h3>About Us <img src="tick.png"></h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the others already answered what CSS to use, I just want to promote an additional approach:

Assuming you have multiple headlines with the styled tick, it makes sense not always have to add the whole `<img />` tag with all its properties everytime.
So it would make sense to just add a class to your `<h3>` like so:

**HTML**

```
<h3 class="blue-bg tick">About You</h3>
```

**CSS**

```
h3.blue-bg {
  background: blue;
  /* and what else you need */
}
h3.tick:after {
  content: '';
  background-image: url("/path/to/your/image-tick.svg");

  /* you need to define the dimensions: */
  background-size: 18px 18px;
  width: 18px; height: 18px;

  /* and what else you need */
}
```

So you can just add your defined class to every element instead of a huge junk of HTML.

*Complete Snippet to try out and fiddle with:*

```css
h3.blue-bg {
  background: #21abe2;
  
  /* and what else you need */
  font-family: helvetica, arial;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
h3.blue-bg.dark {
  background: blue;
  font-style: italic;
}

h3.tick:after {
  content: '';
  background: transparent url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/White_check.svg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: 18px 18px;
  
  /* and what else you need */
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="blue-bg tick">About You</h3>
<br/>
<h3 class="blue-bg tick">Another crazy Headline</h3>
<br/>
<h3 class="blue-bg dark tick">Even with other styles defined</h3>
```